# RStudio Keeps Trying to Load Old Workspace; Cannot do/run anything

Tags: rstudio

I have been having this super annoying issue for a while where I am unable to do anything on RStudio on Mac because I assume it is trying to load a previous environment and variables.

[image]

I have uninstalled RStudio and reinstalled it thinking when I reopen the application, it would give me a clean workspace. To my surprise, it opened the exact same old file, while still having the loading symbol on the environment.

Does anyone have any suggestions?